# Spring Boot 1.2.5, Oracle and Hibernate connection pooling

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, c3p0

I'm profiling my Spring Boot 1.2.5 application and finding the performance to be quite poor. Serving a simple login page takes upwards of 4 seconds under what will be a relatively light load (at this point, JMeter with 500 simulated users).

I'm using VisualVM to try to profile it. It seems that 49% of the applications time is spent getting a connection from Hibernate:

```
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection()    49.121124   4,450,911 ms (49.1%)    0.000 ms    4,573,860 ms    122,949 ms
```

To mitigate this I am trying to enable connection pooling but it does not seem to be working. I have:

Added C3P0 to my dependancies, so my Hibernate dependancies look like this in my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, in my application.properties file, I have added:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.min_size = 50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.timeout = 300
```

I read in the docs that if I have any Hibernate C3P0 property set then the connection pool should be active.

However, I'm not sure it is. When I start Spring Boot, some of the messages I see are:

```
2015-10-28 04:26:23.426  INFO 2182 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.3.Final}
2015-10-28 04:26:23.429  INFO 2182 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-10-28 04:26:23.431  INFO 2182 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-10-28 04:26:23.756  INFO 2182 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-10-28 04:26:24.207  INFO 2182 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

The "hibernate.properties" not found is the one I am concerned with. I realize it may emit that message even if it finds the properties in application.properties.

I'm wondering, have I done something wrong and, is there a way to verify that the connection pooling is actually active?

Thanks very much...

Comment: I don't think you've done anything that would actually enable c3p0. Depending on your setup, you might need to replace the Spring bean that is your application's datasource (to c3p0's `ComboPooledDataSource`) or set a hibernate connection provider class config param `connection.provider_class` to `org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider`. If c3p0 is set up, the library will log a banner and a (long) pool config message at INFO on pool initialization.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but I don;t completely follow. Are you saying I could do this with just another property entry? Currently, It's Spring 4.2 and everything is configured with annotations; no xml. I am @Autowired the JdbcTemplate, and didn't provide my own datasource. If I need to I can, I'm just not clear on how.

Comment: So, i just don't know very much about spring-boot. But purely guessing, I'd try `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider`. Again, you should be able to see c3p0 start up in your logs, as long as you are letting arbitrary messages through at INFO. (otherwise you may need to configure loggers prefixed with  `com.mchange` libs to log at INFO via whatever logging library you use.)

Comment: Thanks again Steve, I think part of the problem is that the versions I am using are different. When I include the property you recommended there is a class not found exception. I'm trying to update my Hibernate all to the latest version (5.x) and figure out what the current, correct, class name is. Also, I may need a dependance for c3p0. Not sure if this will help but once it's downloaded I'll find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Steve Waldman's helpful comments, I got this working. For anyone interested, since I am using Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE, which is based on Spring 4.1.7.RELEASE, Hibernate 5 is not easily available (although I'm working on that).

So to make this work, put this in the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
</dependency>           
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

These properties then work from application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.max_size 2000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.min_size 100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.timeout 5000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.max_statements 1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period 3000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment 2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.validate false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_class = org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@earth-db-11.mit.edu:1521:stardev

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.username=yourun
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.password=yourpw
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

If you prefer, the properties can go into a hibernate.properties file, and they are a little different, like this:

```
hibernate.c3p0.max_size 2000
hibernate.c3p0.min_size 100
hibernate.c3p0.timeout 5000
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements 1000
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period 3000
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment 2
hibernate.c3p0.validate false

hibernate.connection.provider_class = org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@earth-db-11.mit.edu:1521:stardev

hibernate.connection.username=yourun
hibernate.connection.password=yourpw
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

It helped my issue, although not as much as I had hoped.